# Delphi and MS SQL app role

Tags: sql-server, delphi, stored-procedures, ado, vcl

Could someone please explain (step-by-step) how to connect to some MSSQL DB using application role in Delphi (ADO components)? I've created a user in MSSQL DB and application role but calling stored procedure `sp_setapprole` from Delphi app is not working for me..

As far as I know I probably made to many mistakes from the very start, so I would be gratefull for a detailed instructions from the beginning.

Calling sp:

```
ADOStoredProc1->Parameters->ParamByName("@rolename")->Value = "test";
ADOStoredProc1->Parameters->ParamByName("@password")->Value = "test";
ADOStoredProc1->ExecProc();
ShowMessage(ADOStoredProc1->Parameters->ParamByName("@RETURN_VALUE")->Value); //0
```

Comment: Hi Tracer, can you show the code part where you actually call sp_setapprole?

Comment: In addition here is a guide how to properly use application roles: http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/88/posts/10182/working-with-application-role-sql-server.aspx

Comment: I just put TADOStoredProc ond the form, set the parameters via object inspector and call ExecProc method. And what's next?

Comment: On another note, why would you want to use application roles anyway?  You gain nothing concerning security, even worse, any rights assigned to the user's Login or User are completely ignored. This can make security audits and troubleshooting very confusing if the use of Application Roles is not clearly documented and the documentation is accessible... my 2ç

Comment: updated. I simply don't know what to do after I call this sp?

Comment: Here is the link for a C# example : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/63894/Securing-Data-With-Application-Role

Comment: ADOStoredProc1 is calling 'sp_setapprole;1', and that is all the code (properties) regarding sp. I will look further in those articles. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I opened dataset BEFORE calling stored procedure, and that is why it didn't work. Now it's OK. Thanks whosrdady for trying to help :)

Comment: that's why we ask to SHARE code so people like me don't loose time trying to figure out what is wrong... :)